# VC++ debugging mode: batch edit std::vector<int> value?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

Now, in Debugging mode, I have a std::vector vec which contains 100 elements, I'm curious to know whether it's possible to edit these 100 elements at the same time, for instance, make all of them to 1.

The scenario why I have to do that: my project is huge, about 140 thousands lines of codes. Each time I build them, it spend me at least 30 minutes. My project is make up of static libs and one EXE.

Finally, the question i'm asking is
**VC++ debugging mode: batch edit std::vector value?**

****So, don't give me suggestion about my project.****

Anybody can help me?

Update:
What I mean is edit its value in the Watch window. Don't mention my project and build time.

Comment: what do you mean edit them? from your Debugger? or directly in your code? and how would that help you with your build times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open vec in watch window, and send keys "{F2}value{Enter}" multiple times by keyboard macro(e.g.  [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)), then values are changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible using the UI of Watch window.
What I may suggest is to add debug code to your project, such as

```
  static int fill_value = 1;
  std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), fill_value);
```

You should set a breakpoint on the `std::fill` call. When the breakpoint is hit, you can modify `fill_value` in Watch window. After execution is resumed, the vector is initialized to the value you need.

If you need more complex initialization, you might consider reading the contents of the vector from a file.